# Can character abilities and upgrades be used through roadblocks?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

Question in spoiler tags

> Roadblocks prevent diseases from spreading during outbreaks, and also hinder movement. Do they also prevent or hinder usage of character abilities or upgrades which allow the character to interact with adjacent cities? For example, the immunologist can vaccinate an adjacent city, and character upgrades allow treat disease or quarantine (when on a military base) in an adjacent city. Do roadblocks affect these or other similar abilities?

Answer (score 4):

Roadblocks have no effect in these scenarios. They do exactly what they say they do, and nothing else. Since they never mention affecting abilities, they don't.